# is there any free alternative JNBridge? (JMS integration for .NET)

Tags: java, .net, jms

As the subject says, I need some freeware alternative of JNBridge to send messages from .NET application to JMS server on JBoss. I tried searching for anything on google, wikipedia and so but it looks hopeless so far and I'm starting to lose hope. Is there anything available or do I need to tell my superiors that only money can save us?

Comment: Heyy can you find this for me kind of questions are off-topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I felt the same way, but quite often saw similar (much dumbest though) questions wwhich have been answered. Besides I don't ask anyone to start searching for me, I just count on someone that might have this knowledge already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling finds me Stomp and Stompconnect : http://docs.jboss.org/jbossmessaging/docs/usermanual-2.0.0.beta3/html/interoperability.html